# TouchPad not working ubuntu 15.04 on asus Q551LN

Tags: touchpad

I Just installed Ubuntu 15.04 on my Asus Q551LN, but my touchpad is not working, everything seems to work just the touchpad doesn't.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput; dmesg | grep pnp` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following : 
`sudo modprobe -r psmouse`
`sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps`
Hope this helps!